# Convert DISTINCT, COUNT SQL statement to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have this SQL statement (easy to write):

```
select DISTINCT(reg.NCName), COUNT(reg.NCName) as NCCount, ApplyTimesAllowed
from nc_Candidate can Join nc_NCRegion reg on can.NCID = reg.NCID 
                      Join nc_NCContestList con on can.RaceID = con.RaceID
                      Join nc_CandidateToAspUser cau on can.CanID = cau.CanID
Where cau.AspUserID = '835c43ee-6c7c-48d1-b137-6aabf17a829d'
group by reg.NCName, ApplyTimesAllowed
```

and i'm having a really hard time converting this to LINQ.

can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks, Derek

Comment: Distinct on one column only? As that legal SQL?

Comment: yes its correct ... last i checked, sql management studio output the results correctly

Comment: ok i got the linq... just use LINQER to convert the sql
... and here is the linq query (had to modify the linq a bit)

`(from cau in context.nc_CandidateToAspUser
where
  cau.AspUserID == "835c43ee-6c7c-48d1-b137-6aabf17a829d"
group cau.nc_Candidate.nc_NCRegion by new {
  cau.nc_Candidate.nc_NCRegion.NCName,
  ApplyTimesAllowed = cau.nc_Candidate.nc_NCRegion.ApplyTimesAllowed
} into g
select new {
  g.Key.NCName,
  NCCount = g.Count(p => p.NCName != null),
  ApplyTimesAllowed = g.Key.ApplyTimesAllowed
}).Distinct()`